# How to write a function to fill the NaN if other rows having the information

Tags: pandas, dataframe, fillna

i need to fill the information on the NaN with city name having the same store. as the dataset is having few hundreds different stores so i can't fill it one by one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5mXd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Within each store ID, forward fill and backfill your city:

```
pd.concat([df.groupby('store_id')['city'].ffill(),
           df.groupby('store_id')['city'].bfill()], axis=1) \
    .ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

What this does is within groups, forward fill, then within groups, backfill. It then aligns the groups and forward fills across the rows and takes the last column with the filled-in result.

Or alternatively, drop your nulls, drop duplicates, and merge back on the store ID:

```
df.merge(df[['store_id', 'city']].dropna().drop_duplicates(), 
         how='left', on='store_id', validate='m:1')
```